# Finite group G acts on a subset by conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $U\subset G$ such that $|U|$ and $|G|$ are relatively prime. Is the stabilizer of $U$ under conjugation action by $G$ trivial?

Answer (score 1):

No. If the group is abelian, the conjugation action is trivial and the stabiliser of any subset of $G$ is the whole group.